# Using concurrency with python asyncio in requests in Google Cloud Functions

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, concurrency, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-run

I am trying to send requests to the OpenAI API to translate a list of texts via a Google Cloud Function. Since the API takes a little while to answer and I am trying to translate a few hundred texts per day, I tried speeding up the process by sending the requests concurrently from the GCF to the OpenAI API.

So, I prototyped the function in Python in a Jupyter Notebook and managed to get a concurrent function running, knowing that there are some differences in the event loop management, but in the end reducing the run time from about 30 minutes down to 4-5. Then I tried to figure out the differences between running the function in Jupyter and in the Google Cloud Function and in the end managed to get it running there as well.

However, it just doesn't seem to speed up the GCF and still runs for 30 minutes and more, causing TimeoutErrors in other parts of the platform.

I have checked:

1. Resource utilization 400 MB of 8GB are used
2. Concurrent request limit: Set to 8 then realized this setting is only meant for inbound traffic

Here is my code for the cloud function

```py
import pandas as pd
import os

import asyncio

from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
from langchain.prompts.chat import HumanMessagePromptTemplate, ChatPromptTemplate
from langchain.output_parsers import PydanticOutputParser
from langchain.schema.output_parser import OutputParserException 

from langchain.schema.messages import get_buffer_string
from langchain.chains import LLMChain

from functools import wraps


import platform
if platform.system() == "Windows":
    asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())

OPEN_AI_KEY = os.environ.get("OPENAI_TOKEN")
OPENAI_MODEL = "gpt-3.5-turbo-1106"


def request_concurrency_limit_decorator(limit=5):
    # Bind the default event loop
    sem = asyncio.Semaphore(limit)

    def executor(func):
        @wraps(func)
        async def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            async with sem:
                return await func(*args, **kwargs)

        return wrapper

    return executor


async def translate_concurrently(
    df: pd.DataFrame, openai_api_key: str = OPEN_AI_KEY, model_name: str = OPENAI_MODEL
):
    # Creating the prompt
    PROMPT_TRANSLATE_REVIEW = """Translate this into English: '{input}'"""
    llm = ChatOpenAI(openai_api_key=openai_api_key, model_name=model_name)
    message = HumanMessagePromptTemplate.from_template(
        template=PROMPT_TRANSLATE_REVIEW,
    )
    chat_prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages([message])
    chain = LLMChain(llm=llm, prompt=chat_prompt)

    # start async translation requests
    @request_concurrency_limit_decorator(limit=5)
    async def async_translate(chain: LLMChain, input: str):
        resp = await chain.arun({"input": input})
        return resp

    tasks = [async_translate(chain, input=review) for review in df["original_text"]]

    # Row order is guaranteed by asyncio.gather
    df["text_translation"] = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)


def main(ctx):
    # preparing the translation_df with a column "original_text"
    translation_df = pd.DataFrame(...)

    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop.run_until_complete(translate_concurrently(translation_df))
    loop.close()

    return "OK", 200
```

I would appreciate any hints to where I went wrong and why the GCF doesn't speed up as much as my prototyped function in Jupyter Notebook

Comment: Why don't you invoke Cloud Functions for each translation?

Comment: Because then I would have to to manage routing the original_texts to each function, pay multiple instances and make sure the translations end up in the right row in my table, i.e. much more overhead. Also I don't know how to prototype such an architecture, which would increase my dev time significantly.

Comment: Can you have a look at the suggestions shared in this [Document](https://medium.com/syntio/how-we-speed-up-a-google-cloud-function-by-a-factor-of-10-dcc9d3189f4a).

Comment: This is a great article and inspired me to use the semaphore. I couldn't really understand how to use the langchain arun function in conjunction with the session logic in aiohttp though, that's why I opted for the solution without it. I think I might need to rewrite my code along the lines of this article and without langchain, but I would at least like to understand, why it didn't work in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell now, the OpenAI API sometimes needs an extremely long time to answer a request - even upwards of 10 minutes. These calls don't fail and therefore cannot be handled gracefully.

So, the absolute majority of requests are answered within seconds, but every 20 or so prompts, it takes forever and brings down the performance of the whole Cloud Function.

I couldn't find a way to effectively force a timeout within the framework of the langchain library.

In the end, I rewrote the error handling and retrying logic without using langchain. Some requests still run forever, but using asyncio, I can force a timeout and start a new request, which usually runs much faster.